# Declare new class from a Variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, declaration

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like this in Java:

```
Integer a = new Integer(2);
a.getClass() newVariable = new Integer(4);
```

My question is can I declare the type of a new variable by using a variable?

Comment: My question is can I declare the type of a new variable by using a variable in which we store the class that we want?

Comment: Can you please be so kind sircapsalot and give me an example?

Comment: If you already know the type of `a` then it makes no sense still trying to infer it at compile-time. If you don't know the type of `a` then it must be passed in through a generic type meaning you already have the answer. And this particular example doesn't make much sense since an integer can only be `Object` or `Integer` in the first place. What problem are you trying to solve, specifically?

Comment: It was just an example. I could have written                                                     myType var = myType.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(5); But it would have been too ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to specify the type by retrieving it from an other variable.

---

Note that [the reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) of Oracle provide some methods that would simulate it. It will allow you to instantiate an object by specifying it type as a class. But that won't allow you to first specify the object type by retrieving it from the variable.

---

You might want to have a look at [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) which would probably help you fix the hidden problem that made you ask this question.

A simple example would be

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

Note that `T` stands for Type as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

> @param  the type of the value being boxed

So you can give any type.

You can also specify the extends of the type, which kind of give you some security.

```
class Foo<T extends Integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot base the type of a variable on the type of another variable like that.

Depending on your real goal, you might be able to use Java's generics to get around your reason for feeling you want to do that, but it depends a lot on what your real end goal is. For instance, if this is all in class `Foo`, you could parameterize it, and then use the parameter in both places:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public method doSomething() {
        T a = /*...*/;
        T newVariable = /*...*/;
   }
}
```

Then:

```
Foo<Integer> f = new Foo<Integer>();
```

...results in an `f` with a `doSomething` that works with and returns `Integer`s.

Note the `/*...*/` after the `=` in the above: I can't do `new T()` there, which is a famous limitation of Java's generics. The values for `a` and `newVariable` would have to come from somewhere (arguments to the method, for instance, or data members, etc.).

[More about generics here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), again depending on whether they really help with what you're ultimately trying to do.